# Argparse: bypass an argument if another argument is provided

Tags: python, rsa, argparse

Following [this post](https://warrenguy.me/blog/regenerating-rsa-private-key-python) I'm creating a small Python script that can input a public RSA key and output a private RSA key.

It now works by passing the argument this way:

```
./Converter.py -input publikey.pem
```

And this is the code:

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', dest='infile', help="input a .pem file which contains pubilc key")
args = parser.parse_args()
# --- Here we search for n and e ---
PublicKey = args.infile
OpenPublicKey = open(PublicKey, 'r')
ReadPublicKey = OpenPublicKey.read()
TheKey = RSA.importKey(ReadPublicKey)
n = long(TheKey.n)
e = long(TheKey.e)
print 'This is modulus n: ', n, '\n'
print 'This is public exponent e: ', e, '\n'
```

I also want the script to work when there is no public key `.pem` file and in that case the user need to input `n` and `e` this way:

```
./Converter.py -n 7919 -e 65537
```

I'm using `argparse` and basically now Python is extracting `n` and `e` from the `.pem` file.

But I want `argparse` to bypass this extraction when `n` and `e` are provided by the user

Comment: In order to find the private key for a given public key, you will have to factor the modulus `n`. Keep in mind that the modulus `n` should be larger than `e` (actually `λ(n) > e`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!python2
import argparse
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)

group.add_argument('-f','--infile', help="input a .pem file which contains pubilc key")
group.add_argument('-ne',nargs=2, help="value of n and e")

args = parser.parse_args()
# --- Here we search for n and e ---
if args.infile:
    PublicKey = args.infile
    OpenPublicKey = open(PublicKey, 'r')
    ReadPublicKey = OpenPublicKey.read()
    TheKey = RSA.importKey(ReadPublicKey)
    n = long(TheKey.n)
    e = long(TheKey.e)

else:
    n,e=map(long,args.ne)
print 'This is modulus n: ', n
print 'This is public exponent e: ', e
```

For file input:

```
./Converter.py -f publickey.pem
```

For variable input:

```
./Converter.py -ne 4 5
```

Comment: it works @SmartManoj but how argparse knows INFILE as it os not declared in ('-i','--infile', help="input a .pem file which contains pubilc key")? Is it taken from --infile? But that should't be a second option for the command line?

Comment: it takes from the long option '--infile' .[Source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest)

Answer (score 1):

Just add optional keyword arguments for `-n` and `-e`

```
parser.add_argument('-n', type=int)
parser.add_argument('-e', type=int)
```

and if `args.n and args.e` evaluates to `True` then ignore the input argument and skip the code that handles it.